# Lock escalation fix in db2

Tags: sql, db2

There are several lock escalation warning messages in db2 log against table `TD_XYZ`.

Also, it is showing adverse effect on application response time.

Can you suggest how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this shows there is an issue in your application code, because it is putting too many locks at row level.

You can do:

- Review and modify your code.
- Increase the locklist parameter
- Increase the maxlock percentage parameter.